# Full outer join with one selected table

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a complex select statement in my query which I am using three times, for outer joins.  I would like to simplify it to use the complex query once, but this doesn't work:

```
select three.faculty, three.chair, one.students honors, 
  two.students normal, three.students bad
from [complex select statement] one
full outer join
select * from (one) two
on one.faculty=two.faculty and one.chair=two.chair and one.n=two.n
full outer join
select * from (one) three
on two.chair=three.chair and two.faculty=three.faculty and two.n=three.n
```

The version using the complex query repeatedly works:

```
select three.faculty, three.chair,one.students honors,
  two.students normal, three.students bad
from [complex select statement] one
full outer join
select * from [complex select statement] two
on one.faculty=two.faculty and one.chair=two.chair and one.n=two.n
full outer join
select * from [complex select statement] three
on two.chair=three.chair and two.faculty=three.faculty and two.n=three.n
```

Comment: how make it with one select from base and other select from first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't join on a subquery like that.  Instead, you need to use a common table expression, like this (with the apology that I don't know Oracle's syntax exactly):

```
WITH results AS (SELECT lots_of_things FROM lots_of_tables)
SELECT * FROM results
FULL OUTER JOIN results ON (...)
FULL OUTER JOIN results ON (...)
```

Essentially, a CTE means that the database engine will provide the results of the expression as a table-styled value available for the rest of the query (including joins and the like).  Oracle provides [documentation on the `WITH` clause.](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php)